# How can I remove ALL grub2 files and reinstall them? In other words, reset grub2?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 16.04, uefi

I have been using Grub-Customizer ever since I've had Ubuntu, but I've noticed it having more and more issues lately.

About two weeks ago, I reordered the grub entries and put them in sub-menus using grub customizer and saved. It saved like it normally does and reported no errors.

I rebooted to see what it looked like. When my computer boots, it shows me the hardware details before it boots the default EFI. I saw the details, then the screen went black and I saw the details again! It seems to me grub kept rebooting the PC!

I went into the boot menu to load Windows and that worked normally. I created a live Ubuntu USB and booted from it, except, when I saw the grub screen form the USB, I pressed <kbd>C</kbd> for a command line. I have Ubuntu installed on sda9, so I typed:

```
set root=(hd1,9)
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda9
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

And yes, I know how the `(hd1,9)` works, when booting from a USB, the USB is temporarily assigned to `sda`. Ubuntu booted normally so I logged in and tried several things. I tried restoring backups from `/ect/grub.d/backup/`, then tried `sudo update-grub` and got:

```
Syntax Error in Grub.cfg. Please ensure that there are no errors in /ect/grub.d/* and /default/grub.
```

Finally, I tried `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`, and now I can see grub when I start the machine. Now I have another problem. It still shows the same error as before when I type `sudo update-grub`. I would like to reset grub somehow, is there a way to do this? If not, is there a way to even fix this without losing all my programs (again)? Thanks!

Edit: I just realized that the whole `grub.d` folder and the grub default file is GONE! What's going on!?!?!

Comment: We occasionally see systems where flash drive is promoted to sda and that causes all sorts of grief. Especially now that UEFI grub only installs to sda. But is this your build? I found on my systems, if I skipped SATA port, on reboot flash drive would be seen in location of skipped port. Or did you leave SATA0 open?

Answer (score 0):

its /etc not /ect , looks like a typo.

if you wanted to restore grub to defaults then just backup your grub files , purge the grub package and reinstall it.

Comment: You might be able to improve this answer with providing the steps needed in more detail and maybe even adding screen-shots of different parts to make it a rock solid answer.

Comment: Boot-Repair makes it easy with its total uninstall/reinstall options in advanced mode. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Just make sure you have working Internet as it must download new copy of grub.